# How can I add same value added tax for all countries in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, tax, vat

I wanna add 10% tax value for all countries in Magento 2. I can make them 1 by 1 for each country by adding Tax rules under Tax Zones but there should be more effective way which I couldnt find after searching an hour.